# Spectral norm of a sparse Gaussian matrix

Tags: normal-distribution, sparse, random-matrix

Suppose $G$ is an $m \times n$ matrix such that each entry of $G$ is a standard normal variable. We know that the spectral norm of $G$ scales as $\sqrt m + \sqrt n$. Now, given a set of indices $S$ suppose we construct a new matrix $A$ such that $A_{ij} = G_{ij}$ if $(i,j) \in S$, and 0 otherwise. Can we show that the spectral norm of $A$ is upper bounded by the spectral norm of $G$?

edit: The spectral norm is the largest singular value of the matrix:
$\| G \| = \sigma_1(G)$

Answer (score 1):

No, counterexample:

$$
G = \begin{bmatrix}-1& 1& 1\\ 1 &1 &1\\ 1& 1& -1\end{bmatrix}, \qquad A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

The spectral norm of $G$ is 2, the spectral norm of $A$ is about 2.4.

I think in general making things sparse shouldn't have any guaranteed effect on the spectral properties unless there is some additional structure.

Comment: Interesting. @additional structure, I then assume that if G were a Gaussian matrix, things would not necessarily change? What if I zero out "enough" entries? In the extreme case A would be the all 0 matrix and then the result holds of course.

Comment: Actually, I think you could probably say something "with x probability" or even "with high probability" (most of my random examples seem to work as you hypothesized) but I guess my point is you can never guarantee anything. If in a (possibly rare) chance you come across that pathological example, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Ah yea, I think the statement holds with high probability.

Comment: Are we assuming that $S$ doesn't depend on $G$?  That is, for any $S$, the bound holds with high probability over the distribution of $G$?

Comment: @ThomasLumley, yes, let's assume i.i.d. bernoulli.

Answer (score 1):

If the matrix is sufficiently sparse in the right way, then the statement holds with high probability.  [This paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ecp/1465316706) shows that if a random $N\times N$ matrix has $W$ entries per row, with $1\ll W\ll N$, its largest eigenvalue is $O_p(\sqrt{W})$ (under some conditions on the distribution of entries that are satisfied by Gaussians).

This may be more sparsity than you want, though.